# How do I ensure that the list is populated before checking what it contains?

Tags: flutter, list, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore

In the code snippet below, how do I ensure that the senderID list gets populated before checking what the list contains?
I'm pulling data from firestore, storing it in a list, and then checking if it contains a particular key.

```
      Stream<List<Group>> getChatGroups(String grpId) {
        return firestore.collection('groups').snapshots().map((event) {
          List<Group> groups = [];
          List<String> senderIds = [];
    
          for (var document in event.docs) {
            var group = Group.fromMap(document.data());
    
            firestore.collection('groups').doc(group.groupId).collection('chats').get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
              snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                var messageData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                var messages = Message.fromMap(messageData);
                var grId = doc.reference.parent.parent?.id;
    
    //The values in SenderIds should be set before the function below is initiaited 
                senderIds.add(messages.senderId);
    
              });
              
            });
    
    
    //This if function should initiate after getting set above
            if (senderIds.contains(auth.currentUser!.uid)) {
              groups.add(group);
            }
          }
          return groups;
        });
      }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Which line of the code you shared doesn't what you expect it to do? Is there an error message?

Comment: There's not an error exactly, what is happing is the code is returning an empty group. due to the senderID list being empty at the point of the if check. Which is due to the if statement running before the senderIds list getting populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `senderIds.contains` to be called only after *all* of your `Future`s have completed, build a `List` of those `Future`s and use `Future.wait` on that `List`.  Something like:

```dart
var futures = <Future<void>>[];
for (var document in event.docs) {
  // ...

  futures.add(
      firestore
        .collection('groups')
        .doc(group.groupId)
        .collection('chats')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
           // ...
        }),
  );
}

await Future.wait(futures);
if (senderIds.contains(auth.currentUser!.uid)) {
  // ...
}
```

Note that since the above code is asynchronous, you should also be using [`asyncMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) instead of `map`.